# how to fit png background image to the size of imagebutton in android sdk

Tags: android

i have created an image button in my xml

```
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/send" 
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/button_back">
    </Button>
```

and its background like this "button_back.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/back_pressed" /> <!-- pressed png -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/back_focused" /> <!-- focused png -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/back_normal" /> <!-- default png -->
 </selector>
```

its working fine but my problem is that my button width is 50 and my image png width is 70.
how can i fit this png to get resized  to my button width automatically. Right now no matter what width i give to my button its width gets to the size of image png width.

can someone help me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: NOTE: draw9patch is a program the android sdk have in tools directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 9-patch is what you are looking for.

Looks here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html
and search for "Nine-patch" here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Update: It might also be a good idea to scale down your images to fit the 50dip width, and use 9-patch for auto-scaling (when orientation changes for example).

Answer (score 8):

try adding to xml button:

```
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 1):

you need tio use these http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html